# xelatex as default latex engine

Tags: plugin-vimtex

I am new to vim and I am currently working with the default configuration of `vimtex` other than setting my viewer to skim. Here is what `\li` produces with my current `vimtex` configuration (used a minimal test file)

```
System info
  2   OS: macOS 11.2.1 (20D74)
  3   Vim version: VIM 8.2 (1-2164)
  4   Has clientserver: true
  5   Servername: undefined (vim started without --servername)
  6 
  7 VimTeX project: test
  8   base: test.tex
  9   root: /Users/ks/Documents
 10   tex: /Users/ks/Documents/test.tex
 11   out: /Users/ks/Documents/test.pdf
 12   log: /Users/ks/Documents/test.log
 13   aux: /Users/ks/Documents/test.aux
 14   fls: /Users/ks/Documents/test.fls
 15   main parser: current file verified
 16   compiler: latexmk
 17     configuration: 
 18       continuous: 1
 19       callback: 1
 20       latexmk options:
 21         -verbose
 22         -file-line-error
 23         -synctex=1
 24         -interaction=nonstopmode
 25       latexmk engine: -pdf
 26   viewer: Skim
 27   qf: LaTeX logfile
 28     addqflist: 57
 29     fix_paths: 58
 30     set_errorformat: 56
 31   document class: amsart
 32   packages:
 33     amsbsy
 34     amsfonts
 35     amsgen
 36     amsmath
 37     amsopn
 38     amstext
```

How do I make xelatex my default latexmk engine?

I should add that I tried this:

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = { 
         \ 'executable' : 'latexmk',
         \ 'options' : [ 
         \   '-xelatex',
         \   '-file-line-error',
         \   '-synctex=1',
         \   '-interaction=nonstopmode',
         \ ],
         \}
```

but it does not seem to actually run xelatex. (For example, tex documents with `\usepackage{fontspec}` don't compile).

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: For the compiler, i would check the docs (`:help vimtex`, probably). What’s wrong with search (and what search?)? Are you aware of `/` and `?`? We usually prefer one question per question, so I’m trying to decide if this is a related question or something that should be separate.

Comment: Re two questions in one, I agree! I will delete the second question (though the search in question is about going back and forth between the source code and the pdf), but I agree it would be better for it to be a separate question!

Comment: Re my `xelatex` question, I tried a number of things none of which seemed to work; I have looked at the documentation too and I could not work out a way to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [raised](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1967#issue-813597278) the issue with the the author of the plugin and he [suggested](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1967#issuecomment-783630575) the following answer which works:

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk_engines = {
    \ '_'                : '-xelatex',
    \}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392198/vimtex-and-xelatex for setting the engine for only the current file.